# Can smtplib handle email attachments of an unknown file type for python 3.2.3?

Tags: python, python-3.2, smtplib

Looks like when using smtplib I need to know the type of file I would like to attach to an email such as MIMEImage, MIMEText, etc.  Is there a way to handle attachments when the file type is unknown?

User's for our website can upload simple images (jpg and tif) or 3d drawing such as autocad or inventor files.

Thanks!

Andrew